# C# Memory leak in Bitmap

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I got a memory leak in my application in this lines.. If i take a look in the task manager, every time when this process is triggered, the RAM memory is increasing by +- 300 MB..

```
Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(2480, 3508);
panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp1, new Rectangle(0, 0, 2480, 3508));
pictureBox2.Image = bmp1;
```

Can someone help me with his leak? If I use:

```
bmp1.Dispose();
```

I get an exception in "Program.cs" at this line: `Application.Run(new Form1());`
And after this, the application is stopped running...

Screen application:
[image]

Comment: And the exception is? ObjectDisposedExeption?

Comment: Offtopic But avoid looking at task manager and check out Performance monitor instead

Comment: You need to dispose of the image once you are done with it.  Is there a point in your application when you no longer display the image?  If so, that's where you need to dispose of it.

Comment: I think he's repeating the process and the old image is not being cleaned up (at least not right away).

Comment: The image is allways in screen in the picturebox1

Comment: No the exception is: Invalid parameter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update:** You don't have a memory leak *per se*, you just have to wait for the Garbage Collector to free up the resources.

If you *do* want to make the garbage collector `collect` though, you can do this:

```
System.GC.Collect();
System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

---

Why do you need to dispose of the bitmap? If your PictureBox is using it, then you need the bitmap. If you're changing it a lot, maybe you should switch out the old bitmap for a new one and dispose of the old one:

```
Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(2480, 3508);
panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp1, new Rectangle(0, 0, 2480, 3508));
Image img = pictureBox1.Image;
pictureBox1.Image = bmp1;
if (img != null) img.Dispose(); // this may be null on the first iteration
```

Comment: That's the same as calling `Dispose` which is apparently causing an exception.

Comment: I still get the same result as: bmp1.Dispose(); and the application has stopped.

Comment: isn' t it the same as invoking `bmp1.Dispose();` directly?

Comment: It is, but it's better form to use `using`.

Comment: Mmm when I use the clone function, i get an error again.. "Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Drawing.Image'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\Ferry\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Dirk Beprijzing\Dirk Beprijzing\Form1.cs 73 37 Dirk Beprijzing"

Comment: Sorry, my bad, should be `pictureBox2.Image = (Bitmap)bmp1.Clone();`. That being said, the second solution is probably best as I don't think the first one actually answers your question. I've edited the answer to make more sense.

Comment: I'm still discovering the increasing of my used RAM in the application, every time when i trigger this piece of code. Now i have:

using (var bmp1 = new Bitmap(2480, 3508))
            {
                panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp1, new Rectangle(0, 0, 2480, 3508));
                pictureBox2.Image = (Bitmap)bmp1.Clone();
                bmp1.Dispose();
            }

Comment: Yes, the `Clone()` method is not going to dispose of your old image, see my new updated code and try that, let me know how it works. Note, you do not use a `using` block now.

Comment: This one: Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(2480, 3508);
panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp1, new Rectangle(0, 0, 2480, 3508));
Image img = pictureBox1.Image;
pictureBox1.Image = bmp1;
if (img != null) img.Dispose(); // the first time it'll be null

Is increasing the RAM memory as well

Comment: Apparently `Bitmap and Image never close the underlying stream. You'll have an eternal lock on that file, until the GC cares about collecting the floating reference`. So you're relying on the GC still.

Comment: I think u can directly just call: if(pictureBox1.Image !=null){ pictureBox1.Image.Dispose() ;
}  :instead of (the last 3 lines) assigning the image into another Image img reference and disposing it. @AdamKDean what do u think? I was succeded via that actually.

Comment: @SamithaChathuranga No. _Never_ directly call dispose on an image that is referenced in a UI control. It will crash the program on the next UI refresh. Instead, always save a reference to the image object, then replace the image in the UI control (or set it to null to clear it), and only _then_ dispose the saved reference to what it contained.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you should dispose only the image you *don't need anymore*.  You still need the `bmp1` created, you just set it to be the content of the `pictureBox2.Image` field . Try something along these lines:

```
Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(2480, 3508);
panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp1, new Rectangle(0, 0, 2480, 3508));
Bitmap bmp2 = (Bitmap)pictureBox2.Image;
pictureBox2.Image = bmp1;
bmp2.Dispose();
```

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm not experienced with C#, so I might be wrong...</sub>

Comment: Mmm, at this line: Bitmap bmp2 = pictureBox2.Image;
it says: "Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Doesn't make sense, actually you need the Bitmap alive as long the picturebox is displaying it

Comment: @V4Vendetta look again at the code: this is what I meant it to do. It only disposes the image that is not displayed anymore... I don't have C#, but as my answer is basically the same as Adam K Dean's accepted answer, I think it does make sense.

Comment: @Ferry I updated the code with the explicit cast, but a little googling would have solved the problem for you - that error message is not a very uncommon one...

Answer (score 1):

You should use external gdi32.dll for avoiding bitmap memory leaks

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")] 
public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
//your bitmap usage code here
...
//delete bitmap handle when you don't need the bitmap anymore
DeleteObject((IntPtr)hBitmap);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    Bitmap copy_Screen()
    {
        try
        {
            var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
            try
            {
                gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
            return bmpScreenshot;
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        return new Bitmap(10, 10, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Start Stop timer
        if (timer1.Enabled == false) { timer1.Enabled = true; } else { timer1.Enabled = false; }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //memory leak solve
        System.GC.Collect();
        System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        Bitmap BM = copy_Screen();
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = BM;

    }
```

Comment: Why did you post this code? What problem does it solve?