# Out of memory exception when saving screenshot images, even when Disposing each time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this class that save images screenshots of the desktop.

```
#region Class Imports 
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
#endregion

namespace Manager
{
    public class ScreenShot
    {

    #region Global Variables
    private Bitmap _screenShot;
    protected static IntPtr newBMP;
    #endregion

    #region Constants
    public const int SRCCOPY = 13369376;
    public const int SCREEN_X = 0;
    public const int SCREEN_Y = 1;
    #endregion

    #region Class Properties
    [Description("Gets the screenshot image")]
    public Bitmap ScreenImage
    {
        get { return _screenShot; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    [Description("Empty constructor, instantiating _screenShot to nothing")]
    public ScreenShot()
    {
        _screenShot = null;
    }              
    #endregion

    #region Methods

    [Description("Creates an image of the current desktop")]
    public Bitmap GetScreen()
    {
        int xLoc;
        int yLoc;
        IntPtr dsk;
        IntPtr mem;
        Bitmap currentView;

        //get the handle of the desktop DC
        dsk = Win32API.GetDC(Win32API.GetDesktopWindow());

        //create memory DC
        mem = Win32API.CreateCompatibleDC(dsk);

        //get the X coordinates of the screen
        xLoc = Win32API.GetSystemMetrics(SCREEN_X);

        //get the Y coordinates of screen.
        yLoc = Win32API.GetSystemMetrics(SCREEN_Y);

        //create a compatible image the size of the desktop
        newBMP = Win32API.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dsk, xLoc, yLoc);

        //check against IntPtr (cant check IntPtr values against a null value)
        if (newBMP != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            //select the image in memory
            IntPtr oldBmp = (IntPtr)Win32API.SelectObject(mem, newBMP);
            //copy the new bitmap into memory
            Win32API.BitBlt(mem, 0, 0, xLoc, yLoc, dsk, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
            //select the old bitmap into memory
            Win32API.SelectObject(mem, oldBmp);
            //delete the memoryDC since we're through with it
            Win32API.DeleteDC(mem);
            //release dskTopDC to free up the resources
            Win32API.ReleaseDC(Win32API.GetDesktopWindow(), dsk);
            //create out BitMap
            currentView = Image.FromHbitmap(newBMP);
            //return the image
            return currentView;
        }
        else  //null value returned
        {
            return null;
        }    
    }
    #endregion

    public void GetScreenShot(string folder, string name)
    {
        _screenShot = new Bitmap(GetScreen());
        string ingName = folder + name + Elgato_Video_Capture.counter.ToString("D6") + ".bmp";
        _screenShot.Save(ingName);
        _screenShot.Dispose();
    }
    }

}
```

Using it in form1 with a timer:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}
```

And in tick event:

```
ScreenShot shot = new ScreenShot();
public static int counter = 0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter++;
    shot.GetScreenShot(@"e:\screenshots\", "screenshot");
    if (counter == 1200)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        ScreenShotsPlayer ssp = new ScreenShotsPlayer();
        ssp.Show();
    }
}
```

The exception is in the new class on the bottom on the line:

```
_screenShot = new Bitmap(GetScreen());
```

And it happen all the time after saved image number screenshot000147.bmp

```
System.OutOfMemoryException occurred
  HResult=-2147024882
  Message=Out of memory.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status)
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
       at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Image original, Int32 width, Int32 height)
       at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Image original)
       at Youtube_Manager.ScreenShot.GetScreenShot(String folder, String name) in d:\C-Sharp\Manager\Manager\Manager\ScreenShot.cs:line 105
  InnerException:
```

Line 105 is: `_screenShot = new Bitmap(GetScreen())`;

I'm doing a dispose for the _screenShot variable after each save.
Maybe the timer in form1 is too fast ? The timer interval set to 100ms.

Comment: When a variable has no global use, keep it local: Declare the Bitmap within public void getScreenShot(). And the answer to your question is most likely in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957896/c-sharp-memory-leak-in-bitmap

Comment: I think calling `GC.Collect()` will fix the issue.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen The posted code already does a `Dispose`.

Comment: calling dispose do not force the memory to be collected @user2864740

Comment: @dotctor `Dispose` will release system/unmanaged resources. GC.Collect is only needed when there is *no* explicit Dispose (which is a coding contract violation) but the managed object is no longer strongly reachable.

Comment: **If** garbage collection is the solution, a simple GC.Collect may be insufficient. I posted code in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968016/out-of-memory-exception-in-iis/30968569#comment50048808_30968569)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Image.FromHbitmap(newBMP)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k061we7x(v=vs.110).aspx) makes a *copy* based on the source; thus the original `newBMP` is "lost in unmanaged memory" as it is never released.

> The FromHbitmap method makes a copy of the GDI bitmap; so you can *release the incoming GDI bitmap (using the GDI DeleteObject method) immediately after creating the new Image*.